# Why we use the focusable property for View component in react-native?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am new to `react native` and learning about the `View` component. I found a property `focusable` for this `View` component in the [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view#focusable-android) but when I use it, it does not do anything. How can I feel that it is working or not. Can please anyone tell why we use this property and how to use it? A little example will be more appreciated.